# Restarting PC with Yes/No option

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I am trying to create a script to do the following however my coding skills are still not very good.

I want to restart a PC which is idle, however I want to have a popup appear with the Yes or No command to proceed or cancel the restart command.

I was going to do a task schedule to run the idle part and then run a batch file to pop up the yes/no option.

### Update

@boxdog - PC does not lock.

I managed to create a script as per below.

```
@ECHO OFF
SHUTDOWN /S /F /T 60
SET /P continue="You have been idle for more than 10 minutes.                                                                            Your computer is about to shutdown in 60 seconds do you want to abort (y/n): "
IF %continue% EQU y (
SHUTDOWN /A
)
```

Not sure if its possible to change the default blue windows text with the count down? Or maybe someone can tweak my script to work better?

Comment: Won't the PC be locked (and hence the user won't see your message) if it is idle long enough to warrant a restart?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried so far? Could you post any code that you have written so far to try to achieve this?

Comment: @boxdog - PC does not lock. I managed to run this as a batch file:

ECHO OFF :myLabel SHUTDOWN /S /F /T 60 SET /P continue="You have been idle for more than 10 minutes. Your computer is about to shutdown in 60 seconds do you want to abort (y/n): " IF %continue% EQU y ( SHUTDOWN /A

)

Not sure if its possible to change the default windows text with the count down? Or maybe someone can tweak my script to work better?

Much appreciated!

Comment: @BENT17 Please [edit] your question. Code in comments is unreadable.

Comment: Trying to however the format is going back to the above when saving

Comment: updated script in question

Answer (score 0):

There is a [choice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/choice) command if you want to use command prompt:

```
echo off
choice /M "You have been idle for more than 10 minutes. Shutdown"
if %ERRORLEVEL% equ 1 (shutdown /S /F /T 60)
if %ERRORLEVEL% equ 2 (echo no was selected)
```

The `ERRORLEVEL` is starting from 1. So from the examples when you execute `choice /?`:

```
choice /C YNC /M "Press Y for Yes, N for No or C for Cancel."
```

"Y" is 1, "N" is 2, etc.

In Powershell is simpler, but you will have a "default" message:

```
Stop-Computer -Confirm
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to get a custom UI for the countdown - edit the XAML to change the window design.  It accepts the countdown time in seconds (default is 30).  Save as a script and call it like this (for a 60s countdown):

```
powershell.exe -WindowStyle Hidden -File .\script.ps1 60
```

**Note**: if you run as a scheduled task it will only show the dialog window if the logged-on user is the same user the task is running as.

```
Param(
    [Parameter()]
    [int]$TimeOut = 30 # Default to 30 second countdown
)

# Load WPF assembly
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework

# Define WPF window
$window = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load(
    [Xml.XmlNodeReader]::new([xml]@'
    <Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RebootTimer"
            Title="Idle Reboot Alert" Height="195" Width="400" MaxHeight="195" MaxWidth="400" MinHeight="195" MinWidth="400" ShowInTaskbar="False" Topmost="True" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowStyle="ToolWindow">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock x:Name="AlertText" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="14" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center">
                <Run>You have exceeded the 10 min idle timeout.</Run>
                <LineBreak/>
                <Run>The system will restart in ...</Run>
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock x:Name="CountdownText" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="22" FontWeight="Bold" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" />
            <Button x:Name="CancelButton" Grid.Row="2" Height="35" Width="75">Cancel</Button>
        </Grid>
    </Window>
'@)
)

# Get controls to manipulate
$countdownText = $window.FindName('CountdownText')
$cancelButton = $window.FindName('CancelButton')

# Add event handler to cancel button
$cancelButton.Add_Click({$window.Close()})

$window.Add_SourceInitialized({           
    $script:seconds = $TimeOut

    $countdownText.Text = "$($script:seconds)s"

    $script:timer = New-Object System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer
    $script:timer.Interval = ([TimeSpan]'0:0:1.0') # Fire every second

    $script:timer.Add_Tick.Invoke({   
        $countdownText.Text = "$($script:seconds)s"

        if($script:seconds-- -le 0) {
           Restart-Computer
        }
    })

    $script:timer.Start()
})

# Show the window
$window.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```